# What is the difference between Material-UI DataGrid and Material-UI Table?

Tags: reactjs, datatable, datagrid, material-ui

What is the difference between [Material-UI DataGrid](https://material-ui.com/components/data-grid/demo/) and [Material-UI Table](https://material-ui.com/components/tables/)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Quoted from [Material UI Docs](https://material-ui.com/components/tables/#data-table)

> The `Table` component has a close mapping to the native 
> elements.
>
> The `DataGrid` component is designed for use-cases that are focused
> around handling a large amounts of tabular data. While it comes with a
> more rigid structure, in exchange, you gain more powerful features.

Comment: What features, for example?

Comment: @it-alien Sorting, selecting, filtering and etc.

Comment: But it seems I can do these all with <TableRow>s (<tr>s), can't I?

Comment: @it-alien You can write everything from scratch if you want to.

Comment: @it-alien I personally use headless libraries like https://react-table-v7.tanstack.com/.